# How to find $2$nd diffirential of $ u = \frac{x}{y}$

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Here's the function:

$$ u = \frac{x}{y}$$

and
$$du = \frac{ydx - xdy}{y^2}$$

but how to find $d^2u$ then?

I know that there's the formula:

$$d^nf(x,y,z) = \left( dx \frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}+dy\frac{\partial}{\partial{y}} +dz\frac{\partial}{\partial{z}}\right)^nf(x,y,z)$$

Is it correct to apply here? And also how would deferential look (in detail), if apply it here?

Comment: You may consider $yu=x$ instead and differentiate both sides twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$du=\frac { ydx-xdy }{ y^{ 2 } } \\ { d }^{ 2 }u=d\left( \frac { ydx-xdy }{ y^{ 2 } }  \right) =\frac { d\left( ydx-xdy \right) { y }^{ 2 }-d\left( { y }^{ 2 } \right) \left( ydx-xdy \right)  }{ { y }^{ 4 } } =\frac { \left( dydx+y{ d }^{ 2 }x-dxdy-x{ d }^{ 2 }y \right) { y }^{ 2 }-2ydy\left( ydx-xdy \right)  }{ { y }^{ 4 } } =\\ =\frac { \left( { y }^{ 3 }{ d }^{ 2 }x-{ y }^{ 2 }x{ d }^{ 2 }y \right) -\left( 2{ y }^{ 2 }dxdy-2yx{ \left( dy \right)  }^{ 2 } \right)  }{ { y }^{ 4 } } =\frac { { y }^{ 2 }{ d }^{ 2 }x-{ y }x{ d }^{ 2 }y-2{ y }dxdy-2x{ \left( dy \right)  }^{ 2 } }{ { y }^{ 3 } }  $$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
u &=& \dfrac xy \\
yu &=& x \\
y \ \mathrm du + u \ \mathrm dy &=& \mathrm dx \\
(y \ \mathrm d \mathrm du + \mathrm dy \ \mathrm du)+(u \ \mathrm d \mathrm dy + \mathrm du \ \mathrm dy) &=& \mathrm d \mathrm dx \\
\mathrm d \mathrm du &=& \dfrac{\mathrm d \mathrm dx - 2\mathrm du \ \mathrm dy - u \ \mathrm d \mathrm dy}{y} \\
&=& \dfrac{\mathrm d \mathrm dx - 2\left(\frac{y\ \mathrm dx - x \mathrm dy}{y^2}\right) \ \mathrm dy - \left(\frac xy\right) \ \mathrm d \mathrm dy}{y} \\
&=& \dfrac{y^2 \mathrm d \mathrm dx - 2\left(y\ \mathrm dx - x \mathrm dy\right) \ \mathrm dy - xy \ \mathrm d \mathrm dy}{y^3} \\
&=& \dfrac{y^2 \mathrm d \mathrm dx - 2y\ \mathrm dx \ \mathrm dy + x \ \mathrm dy \ \mathrm dy - xy \ \mathrm d \mathrm dy}{y^3} \\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

I was basically confused about the formula I've put in the original question

$1$-st differential is very easy

$$du = \left(dx\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}} + dy\frac{\partial}{\partial{y} } + dz\frac{\partial}{\partial{z}}\right)$$

then I was confused about $2$-nd:

$$d^2u = \left( dx\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}} + dy\frac{\partial}{\partial{y} } + dz\frac{\partial}{\partial{z}}\right)'dx + \left( dx\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}} + dy\frac{\partial}{\partial{y} } + dz\frac{\partial}{\partial{z}}\right)'dy + \left( dx\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}} + dy\frac{\partial}{\partial{y} } + dz\frac{\partial}{\partial{z}}\right)'dz $$

and finally:

$$d^2u = dx^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2x} + dxdy\frac{\partial^2}{\partial{x}\partial{}y} + dxdz\frac{\partial^2}{\partial{x}\partial{z}} \ldots$$